# Prevent PointerReleased event handler from firing if onClick event happens

Tags: c#, uwp

I currently have a UWP app that shows a list of videos and when the user clicks on them the video starts playing, if the user touches the screen then it ends. Problem is the way it's working now PointerReleased (the event that stops the video and hides the player's visibility) fires right after onClick, so the video is never shown.

Additionally a random video will start playing when the app has been idle for some time, this is seen on the IsIdle variable.

I've tried setting the button event to PointerReleased as well but that doesn't seem to do anything and I can't use PointerPressed to stop the video because then it would conflict with another event I have.

My question is, is there a way to prevent the PointerReleased event from firing right on that moment? These methods are located in different classes if that changes anything.

For some context, the method that starts the video is this:

```
        private async void startVideo(StorageFile video)
        {
            playing = true; 
            App.Current.IsIdle = true;
            Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream stream;
            stream = await video.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
            player.SetSource(stream, video.ContentType);
            //VideoFadeIn.Begin(); 
            player.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            //playerContainer.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; 
        }
```

And when IsIdle changes to false through this method:

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerReleased += onCoreWindowPointerMoved;   

        private void onCoreWindowPointerMoved(CoreWindow sender, PointerEventArgs args)
        {
            idleTimer.Stop();
            idleTimer.Start();
            IsIdle = false;
        }
```

This method is called:

```
public void onIsIdleChanged(Frame frame)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"IsIdle: {App.Current.IsIdle}");
        if (App.Current.IsIdle == true)
        {
            player.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            //VideoFadeIn.Begin();
            if(!playing)
                playRandomVideo();
        }
        if (App.Current.IsIdle == false)
        {
            //VideoFadeIn.Stop();
            player.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            stopVideo();
            if (!playingSelected)
                frame.Navigate(typeof(Calculadoras));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use a flag? like setting `flag=true` in `onClick` then `if(flag==true) flag = false; return;` in `PointerReleased`

Comment: It's always the simplest solutions... Seems like I had a mental block trying to come up with a more complex solution.

Answer (score 0):

As Vijay pointed out on my original post's comment, I could simply create a flag. So for anyone in the future in a similar scenario, here's how I did it:

1- Created the flag `bool clickedSelected;` that's initialized on `false`.

2- When a video is clicked change it to `true`:

```
playingSelected = true;
clickedSelected = true;
startVideo(video);
```

3- On the `OnIsIdleChanged` event make sure to change it back to false after everything was skipped:

```
public void onIsIdleChanged(Frame frame)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"IsIdle: {App.Current.IsIdle}");
        if (App.Current.IsIdle == true)
        {
            //VideoFadeIn.Begin();
            if (!playing)
                playRandomVideo();
        }
        if (App.Current.IsIdle == false)
        {
            //VideoFadeIn.Stop();
            if (!clickedSelected)
            {
                stopVideo();
                if (!playingSelected)
                    frame.Navigate(typeof(Calculadoras));
                else
                    playingSelected = false;
            }
            else
            {
                App.Current.IsIdle = true;
                clickedSelected = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I thought I can post this as the answer but its ok